# what are the jar files to add in "add external jars" for XMLfile processing using mapreduce in eclipse ide

Tags: xml, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce

for processing xml input file using mapreduce programing what are the jar files to add to "add external jars" in eclipse ide

I am importing jar files which are preseted in mapreduce,common,common-lib,yarn

am I need to add any other jar files except above four for xml file data processing
 please healp me
thank you

Answer (score 0):

you'd better import the jars in this folder ;

```
hadoop-2.5.0\share\hadoop\hdfs
```